# Equivalent to "- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;" in Apple Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

New to S.O.

Currently going through  [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1):

And there's instructions for using Objective C Code. What would be the equivalent Swift code?

Or should I just begin to use Swift / Playground?

Cheers!

Comment: Too narrow and unlikely to be of use to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@IBAction func unwindToList(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!)
```

1. IBActions are indicated by `@IBAction`
2. Methods are declared with `func`
3. Parameters are named first and then given a type with a `: TypeName`
4. All pointers to objects in Objective-C get converted to Implicitely Unwrapped Optionals because they can be nil when normally in Swift a variable cannot be

More Info on Implicitely Unwrapped Optionals:

> “These kinds of optionals are defined as implicitly unwrapped
>   optionals. You write an implicitly unwrapped optional by placing an
>   exclamation mark (String!) rather than a question mark (String?) after
>   the type that you want to make optional.” ...
>
> “An implicitly unwrapped optional is a normal optional behind the
>   scenes, but can also be used like a nonoptional value, without the
>   need to unwrap the optional value each time it is accessed. ”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks